# React Native - Wrapping an app container in a ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, navigation, containers

I'm attempting to wrap the entirety of my navigation in a scrollable container.

Though I've tried, I am unable to find the right permutation of flex properties, `style` vs. `contentContainerStyle`, etc. that results in a `ScrollView` surrounding an app container actually being scrollable.

All is well with the following:

```
class Asdf extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 100
                    }}
                >
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    flexGrow: 1
                }}
            >
                <Asdf />
            </ScrollView>
    );
  }
};
```

Rendering the navigator and its app container, though, immediately causes it to "max out" its scrolling capabilities and perform the ricochet animation on my iPhone with any kind of scroll:

```
class Asdf extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 100
                    }}
                >
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const
    Hjkl = createStackNavigator({
        Asdf: Asdf
    }),

    Qwer = createAppContainer(Hjkl);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    flexGrow: 1
                }}
            >
                <Qwer />
            </ScrollView>
    );
  }
};
```

---

Many thanks to whoever is able to provide the probably one line of code that makes this work properly.

I tried to determine it, really.

Comment: inside scrollView, try to remove contentContainerStyle and use style={{ flex: 1 }}

Comment: @HazimAli No dice.